# Manipulate json data in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In Ember, how would you manipulate a specific json string.

Lets say I want to manipulate every "field2" so it says "stringplusmore" instead of just "string".

I'm confused whether I should use Enumerables or something else. Or it should be in the Array or Object controller. Or maybe a view?

An example would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
[  
   {  
      "field1":"string",
      "field2":"string",
   },
   {  
      "field1":"string",
      "field2":"string",
   }
]
```

Comment: IS there a specific reason you dont want to load your objects in DataStore ? using Ember Data ?

Comment: I've never read this, but it looks like a okay alternative to the Ember tutorials: http://www.williamhart.info/an-emberjs-beginners-tutorial.html I recommend really reading it over a few times. Then head back to the ember cookbook and look at how they are working with models.

Comment: @lame_coder Why do you think I don't load my objects in DataStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just modifying the json before it hits the page, do it in the route.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return $.getJSON('/items').then(function(data){
      data.forEach(function(item){
        item.field2 += 'plusmore';
      });
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/881/edit

Comment: But you can't use .then(function(data) with ember data right?
Like this:
`return this.store.find('item').then(function(data)`

Comment: You can use it, but you won't be accessing the json, you'd be accessing the collection returned from Ember Data.  Personally I think Ember is a big enough learning curve, throwing Ember Data in just muddies the already deep waters.  Ember works perfectly fine with POJOs.